# View.OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Hi guys a my friend have written a project,he pass me this project and I imported it with eclipse,I have corrected some errors given because I don't use the library.Now remain a only error and I don't know how resolve it.
PS:To my friend,the project works and run without errors.
The errors give me is as of title.
This is the code:

```
 package it.sapienzaapps.ingvterremoti.beAlerted.object;

import javax.swing.text.View;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public abstract class FriendPicker {

    private Drawable icon;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    private int requestCode;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;
    protected abstract View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener();

    public FriendPicker(Drawable icon, String text1, String text2,
            int requestCode) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }
    public int getRequestCode() {
        return requestCode;
    }
    public void setRequestCode(int requestCode) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }
    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public String getText1() {
        return text1;
    }
    public void setText1(String text1) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public String getText2() {
        return text2;
    }
    public void setText2(String text2) {
        this.text2 = text2;
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Marko Devcic said.  Plus that import of `javax.swing.View` looks to be the wrong class to import for Android.

Change this line

```
import javax.swing.text.View;
```

To this:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this import:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
protected abstract View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener();
```

to this

```
protected View.OnClickListener clickListener;
```

You are defininga a variable of type OnClickListener, and the compiler expects a name, not a method call

Comment: What does the `abstract` modifier do for the variable declaration?